# Need Device Info from LG Optimus

Tags: android

I have users reporting some problems with a specific camera preview size that the LG Optimus reports as a supported size but fails to draw to my surface view. Other preview sizes it supports work fine.

I'd like to hack around this by removing that supported size from the prefs in my app but need to be able to identify this model.

Would some kind folks with an LG Optimus kindly share the Build.Device, Build.Model and Build.Manufacturer to me as in..

```
Log.d("deviceInfo", String.format("DEVICE: %s MANU: %s MODEL: %s", 
            Build.DEVICE,
            Build.MANUFACTURER,
            Build.MODEL
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean Optimus One:

```
DEVICE: thunderg MANU: LGE MODEL: LG-P500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DEVICE: thunderc MANU: LGE MODEL: VM670
```

This is an LG Optimus V with Virgin Mobile USA.